# go dep not running on docker-compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

My problem is docker-compose always return:

`golang_1    | bash: dep: command not found`

It's my `docker-compose.yml` :

```
    version: "3"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: mini_api
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd
      POSTGRES_DB: mini-api
    volumes:
      - ./db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql
    ports:
    - "5433:5432"

  golang:
    image: golang:1.11.0-stretch
    volumes:
      - ./:$GOPATH/src/github.com/bagusandrian/mini-api
    working_dir: $GOPATH/src/github.com/bagusandrian/mini-api
    links:
        - postgres
    ports: 
      - "8000:9090"
    command: bash -c "dep ensure -v && go build -v && ./mini-api"
```

I run with command: `docker-compose up` and always return:

```
golang_1    | bash: dep: command not found
```

Any false in my `docker-compose.yml` or I missing something?

You can pull from my repo: http://github.com/bagusandrian/mini-api

Comment: `dep` is not in that docker image

Comment: U can pull from my repo: http://github.com/bagusandrian/mini-api

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `go dep` first. Add this to your images

```
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
```

Or to the compose file:

```
command: >
    bash -c "go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
    && dep ensure -v && go build -v && ./mini-api"
```

Comment: where i add this command? Sorry im very beginner for docker-compose.

Comment: add it before `dep ensure`, i also recommend using docker file instead of command field

Comment: `/home/nakama/gopath/src/github.com/bagusandrian/mini-api is not within a known GOPATH/src`
I already try, but got error

Comment: you need to run `go build` with the sources, as error claims.